# Is it possible to use start init.d service using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, systemd, init.d

Ansible will fail the task below

```
- name: Start opendj
  service: name={{opendj_service_name}} state=started enabled=yes
```

because the service is a init.d service and not systemd

Is it possibe to start a init.d service using Ansible?

Comment: Questions about the Linux operating system should, instead, be asked on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry but it is very clear to all that the question is not about Linux, it is about Ansible. For some reason it is not clear to you. Infrastructure, Linux etc is becoming more and more a development discipline with Ansible, Chef, Infrastructure as Code so be prepared to downvote a lot more questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried as below

```
- name: make sure {{opendj_service_name}} is started
  sysvinit:
      name: {{opendj_service_name}}
      state: started
      enabled: yes
```